# Restrict deployment of iOS Apps to only certain apps

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

Is there any way to limit my iOS app be available for Gen 2 iPads or better and iPhone 4 or better in the app store?  I can do this in Android so I imagine their is an iOS equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict your app to specific devices, but you can configure it to require certain hardware features by including the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your Info.plist.

This is an array of strings, you can find details about which keys are available in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW9).

By including "front-facing-camera", for example, you would essentially restrict your app to iPhone 4, iPad 2 and latest-gen iPod touch.

Comment: This is correct, but note that you can't include "front-facing-camera" unless your application absolutely needs the front facing camera to function. Same is true for all other keys.

Comment: Good point. Frankly, I don't really see why one would even want to restrict an app so arbitrarily.

Comment: We have a project that uses a lot of graphics memory, and currently it is running out of memory on iPad 1 but not iPad 2. If it means we have to remove or delete graphics for all users, this would be a big shame because it limits the user's experience if they have a better iPad too.